# Can I access Outlook Email contacts field in VBA?

Tags: outlook

I would like to access the contacts field on an email message (Email options) in outlook. Normally this field ties an email to a contact. Since it is a freeform text field available from the options dialog box, I am trying to use it to store a "next action" for my email message. I would like to set the next action based on the subject but I can't figure out how to access thas field from the outlook.mailitem object

Thanks
Jim

Comment: Just to clarify - I assume you're trying to access the actual "Contacts" field that would be seen when designing a form, rather than the "To:" field for example?  Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve, just to add a little more context to your question?

Comment: Not sure how the Contacts field relates to "actions" in your use-case but an intriguing question none the less. I also couldn't figure out how this field is accessible so far.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will answer it: the field is buried in a semi-generic 'Links' property, with a type of olContact.  To test the following code, open a new email, put something in the contacts field, and then run the code:

```
Sub ShowContactsField()
  Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim ActiveMailItem As Inspector
  Dim currLink As Link
```

Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  If TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then
    If objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
      For Each currLink In objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Links
        If currLink.Type = olContact Then
          MsgBox currLink.Name
        End If
      Next
    End If
  End If
  Set objApp = Nothing
End Sub

In general, I agree with Oliver; this probably isn't the best place to store what you're looking for, but at least it's exposed in the native form.  Check the field length, I think it might be limited to 255.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I also couldn't figure out how to access the Contacts field but from your description it sounds like you're not intending to use it for its intended purpose at all but rather just have the need to associate some arbitrary string data with an email item. If that is correct, I would recommend adding fields to the `UserProperties` collection instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are easier way to get Contacts list - by using Links property of oMailItem object:

```
    For i = 1 To mailItem.Links.Count
        If mailItem.Links.item(i).Type = olContact Then
                Debug.Print mailItem.Links.item(i).Name
        End If
Next i
```